# Equivalent to BindPropertyAttribute in ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

Due to limitations imposed by a hosting provider, I am forced to use ASP.NET Core 1.1.

I have created a model class and wish to have that model bind to a named value that is different to the name of the model property.

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 onward, I would use the `BindPropertyAttribute` as follows:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [BindProperty(Name="g-recaptcha-response")]
    public string GoogleReCaptchaResponse { get; set; }
}
```

However, the `BindPropertyAttribute` is not supported in ASP.NET Core 1.1. Is there an alternative I can use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ModelBinder` attribute :

```
[ModelBinder(Name = "g-recaptcha-response")]
public string GoogleReCaptchaResponse { get; set; }
```

In the view , you should set the element `name` to `g-recaptcha-response` for model binding:

```
<input name="g-recaptcha-response" class="form-control" />
```